# Zbar scanner image box not repositioning right

Tags: ios, autorotate, zbar

I have the following code to put an scanner box image around the scanning region for Zbar:

```
    -(UIView *)myOverlay
{

    float width = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
    float height = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,width,height)];

    float imgX = 0;//width*0.12;
    float imgY = height*0.25;
    float imgW = width;
    float imgH = height*0.50;

    UIImageView *FrameImg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(imgX,imgY,imgW,imgH)];
    [FrameImg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"scan_box_t.png"]];
    [FrameImg setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin];
    [view addSubview:FrameImg];

    //view.autoresizesSubviews = true;

    return view;
}
```

Problem is, when I rotate my iPhone, the overlay view that this method generates doesn't move the image to the centre of the screen. The auto resizing mask I found from searching for a solution didn't appear to make a difference. The image is facing the right way up  - but is aligned to the left of the screen, not centre. What should I do?

Edit: see below:

http://speedy.sh/dj8Sw/IMG-L.jpg

http://speedy.sh/EbqC4/IMG-P.jpg

IMG-L is the Landscape orientation, the other is portrait. The Portrait one is how it's supposed to look with the image starting at 25% width and height of the screen and the image itself have a width and height of 50% of the screen.

Edit 2: Code that executes on rotation:

```
-(void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
                                duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    //reader.cameraOverlayView.bounds.size = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    //reader.readerView willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];
    //[reader.readerView setNeedsLayout];
    [reader.cameraOverlayView.FrameImg removeFromSuperview];

}
```

Comment: add some screen shots

Comment: You can recognize the orientation of your screen and load the correct image, did you tried this ?

Comment: Not before you asked although I did try resizing the image and changing orientation via will rotate to interface orientation. I just now tried removing it so I could re-add it via that method too, but the removing code doesn't know the image exists. Not sure how to get around that at the moment.  See my OP for the method.